# Ключи в команде apt-get в терминале linux

Tags: linux, terminal, apt-get

Я недавно искал как полностью снести заглючившую  MySQL. Нашел команду. Она мне помогла, но я не могу найти, что значит ключ `"-V"`.
Для `--verbose` сокращенная форма -`"-v"`, а тут не могу понять.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* -V
```

Comment: @VladVetrov а в моём мануале -V есть

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего  -V  в:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* -V
```

Показывает версию удаляемого пакета. Т.е. вы удаляете по маске mysql* и -V помогает узнать какой именно пакет будет удален.

```
-V, --verbose-versions
Show full versions for upgraded and installed packages.
```